# Number of Elements in Array that are lower or equal to

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class ArrayExercise
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        int arr[] = { 3, 4, 14, 32, 45, 61, 32, 18, 9, 38, 99, 42 };
        int sentinel = 42;
        int count = 0;
        ;

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

            if (arr[i] != sentinel) {
                count++;
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

I want to count all the elements in the array that are less than 23 using 42
as a comparison value (Sentinel Value). I am stuck on how to implement the second part of the comparison. Currently my array only counts the number of elements that are not 42.

The expected output is 5 since 5 of the elements coming before 42 are less than 23 (3, 4, 14, 18 and 9 are). Observed output from my code is 11.

By sentinel value I mean that if the array is not completely filled out, counting should still stop when the sentinel value, 42, is encountered. Example:

```
int arr[] = { 3, 14, 32, 45, 18, 38, 42, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
```

Here the expected output is 3 because 3 of the elements before 42 are less than 23 (3, 14 and 18).

Comment: "number of elements in the array that are less than 23 using 42 as my comparison value" - I'm sorry, but I cannot understand what this means. (BTW, please indent your code correctly as it makes it much easier for both you and me to read)

Comment: Why do you have `else { break; }`? You realize that ends the loop as soon as `Arr[i]` *does* equal `K`.

Comment: I want the loop to end when it reaches the end of the array.

Comment: @LaloG `for (int i = 0; i < Arr.length; i++){` does that.

Comment: Please when asking people here (or elsewhere) to read and understand your code, indent it properly and adhere to the naming conventions. Class name is `Array` with capital `A` (or better `ArrayExercise`), variables begin with small letters, so `arr` and `k` (or better `sentinel`).

Comment: You need to change your logic to instead break when you see the sentinel (`array[i] == sentinel`) and only increment the count when the current value is less than the upper bound (`array[i] < 42`).

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a second `if` statement inside the first one.

Instead of this:

```
if (arr[i] != sentinel) {
    count++;
}
else {
```

do something like this:

```
if (arr[i] != sentinel) {
    if (/* put condition here */) {
        count++;
    }
}
else {
```

I’m sure you can fill in the missing condition in the innermost `if`.